# C++ assign and check in one line?

Tags: c++, assign

I have a function my_fun which returns random number.

How can I do declaration and value check in one line?

```
int x;
```

1. `if (x= my_fun()<0)`
2. `if ((x= my_fun())<0)`
3. `if ((x= my_fun()<0)) // this is what my IDE suggests but looks strange since those extra braces don't help at all.`

Comment: Do you mean "how can I do declaration" or do you mean "how can I do definition". Aside from that, I would suggest you do the definition on a separate line to improve code readability (in my opinion). There is also a lot of risk that you are assigning the result of `my_func() < 0` to `x` rather than what you intended.

Comment: Please, do it in two lines. The code will be easier to read, understand and maintain. It will be just as fast and the compiler will generate the same assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments of @Bas and @Jeffrey, prefer to do it in two lines. However, in C++17, you could do it like so

```
if (int x = my_func(); x < 0) {
 // Do stuff
}
```

To explain the difference between your options:

- Options 1) and 3) : `x` will have the value of the expression `my_fun() < 0` and not the value returned by `my_fun()`. They are basically the same, the extra parentheses do noting. You could as well write `(((( x = my_fun() < 0 ))))`
- Option 2) : Will assign the value returned by  `my_fun()` to `x` and then evaluate `x < 0`, which is what you probably want.

Comment: You asked about declaration and value check in one line. But If I HAD to pick one of the three, I would pick the second one. But again, I'd prefer declaration a different line than the value check

Comment: Personally I don't like `auto` there since you have to check carefully to see if `<` is not overloaded. But I like this approach since `x` doesn't leak into the surrounding scope.

Comment: Agreed, nothing to gain from `auto` here